# Drupal add content in another content's form

Tags: forms, drupal, drupal-7, entityreference

I'm using Drupal 7 and I'm currently facing the following problem:

I have a database that among other data consists of *addresses* and *services*. The relationship is such that every *service* needs to have an *address* (just one). In Drupal both *addresses* and *services* are content types and a *service* has a field that relates it to an address (using [EntityReference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) module).

When creating a new *service* users can choose an existing *address* for it, but the *address* needs to be created beforehand. I would like to know of it's possible to create a content creation form for *service* that would contain all the fields for *address* as well. If the user would fill all the fields by hand, a new *service* and a new *address* would be created. There should also be an option to choose an address (from a list or suggestion box). Upon doing so the address fields would be automatically populated with data from an already existing *address* and, when submitted, the form would result in creation of a new *service* related to a previously existing *address* (just like it works now). I did a very similar thing in Django and it was very easy and didn't require a very application-specific code. I was wondering if there is a just as simple way to do it in Drupal.

To put it shortly - I'm looking for a *service* content creation form that gives the choice choice between choosing an existing *address* or creating a new one "in-place" (i.e. in the same form).

I would also like to add that I'm relatively new to Drupal (although I have php experience) and it's difficult for me to properly name the problem I'm facing. As a result it's quite possible that the title of this question is not relevant and/or this issue has been addressed in another question (and yes, I searched for it). If that is the case, feel free to just point me in the right direction.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [references dialog module](http://drupal.org/project/references_dialog) should be just what you need!  It should allow you to add a referenced node without leaving your current edit screen!

It doesn't place the fields right in there, but you don't have to leave the screen to create a referenced node.

Is this what you had in mind?